# Azure Single Sign on post request giving 403 forbidden error

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, azure, spring-mvc, single-sign-on

I am working on the jsp-springboot application ,I have implemented the sso using azure and it is working as expected. I have configured

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id

azure.activedirectory.client-id

azure.activedirectory.client-secret
```

Also I have added the redirect url as well
In the application.properties , I have not added any configuration classes other that these changes, I am able to login successfully also the ajax **GET** calls are returing 200 response code, but for **POST** calls are giving 403 forbidden error

get call sample

```
$.ajax({​​​​​
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/getvalue/"+productId,
  contentType: "text/plain",
  dataType: 'json',
   
  success: function (data) {​​​​​
     console.log("Success");
  }​​​​​,
  error: function (e) {​​​​​
    console.log("There was an error with your request...");
   
  }​​​​​
}​​​​​);
```

And the post call

```
  $.ajax({​​​​​
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/saveValue",
      data:JSON.stringify(valueObj),
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (data) {​​​​​
      console.log("success: ");
      }​​​​​,
      error: function (e) {​​​​​
        console.log("There was an error with your request...");
       
      }​​​​​
    }​​​​​);
```

I am not sure why the post calls are not working

Comment: is server expecting csrf token?

Comment: @sdoxsee I have not configured any filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 on a GET and 403 on a POST tells me that you still have CSRF enabled.

> CSRF protection is enabled by default in the Java configuration. We can still disable it if we need to:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
}
```

ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf#1-java-configuration

I wouldn't recommend disabling it though. You could look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.0-RC1/reactive/exploits/csrf.html#webflux-csrf-configure-custom-repository

Comment: I tried your code and the post call was working successfully. Let me go through the link you have sent. I will accept this answer once it works properly